# Where is the shared folder in the guest CentOS of VirtualBox?

Tags: centos, virtualbox, shared-folders

I am running CentOS 7 on the VirtualBox.
CentOS image is CentOS-7-x86_64-DVD-2009.iso downloaded from here [http://mirror.kakao.com/centos/7.9.2009/isos/x86_64/]
and the Host OS is Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC

In the VirtualBox setting > SharedFolders > Machine Folders,
I created a shared folder with folder path  'C:\Users\myname\Documents\temp1', folder name 'temp1',
read-only option off, and auto-mount option on, mount point option blank and make permanent option on.
I expected that the files in the 'folder path' in the host appear somewhere in the guest OS,
somewhere like /media, /home, /usr, /usr/local. But I can't find anything.

Where are the shared folder and the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good Evening,

you have to make and name a sharefolder in Linux, lets name it share.
Then you mount it via

sudo mount -t vboxsf -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000 share ~/host

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?t=15868

Just had the same problem with vmware :D